# Could not save data. Error: Extension must have a title

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

In my Joomla! site, whenever I try to save the config option of any component I get the following error.

```
Could not save data. Error: Extension must have a title.
```

This was working correctly until recently, I even tried switching to a previous DB backup thinking something might have been messed up inside the `assets` or the `extensions` table, but still the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found that value `id` was being passed with POST request, but it somehow was not being received in the controller.

Later I figured that in the `/administrator/index.php` as a requirement for a certain 3rd party library, I had added the code to unset the `$_POST['id']` which was causing the administrator controller to receive everything except the ID for an object on form submit. Once I added the additional check before unseting the `id` key, everything started working flawlessly.